# Updating dataframe in R without for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, match, apply

I have one master dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(c("A", "B", "C"), c(1,2,3), c(3,1,2), c(4,2,1), rep(NA, 3), rep(NA, 3))
colnames(df) <- c("text", "var1", "var2", "var3", "value1", "value2")
```

And another dataframe `df.upd` with new information:

```
df.upd <- data.frame(c(1,2), c(3,1), c(4,2),c(0.5, 0.6), c(12, 20))                           
colnames(df.upd) <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "value1", "value2")
> df
text var1 var2 var3 value1 value2
1    A    1    3    4     NA     NA
2    B    2    1    2     NA     NA
3    C    3    2    1     NA     NA
> df.upd
  var1 var2 var3 value1 value2
1    1    3    4    0.5     12
2    2    1    2    0.6     20
```

I want to match columns "var1", "var2", "var3" and update the columns "value1" and "value2". So row 1 and 2 of `df.upd` would update row 1 and 2 of `df`, ergo `as.numeric(df.upd[row x, 1:3])==as.numeric(df[row y, 2:4])` must be `TRUE`.

The master df has around 30k rows and 60 columns, so a for loop is not an option. Any idea how to accomplish this faster?

Comment: you can use `merge` with `all.x = TRUE` (left join), then use `ifelse` with `is.na` to update the relevant columns, then drop extra columns

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347213/r-data-table-update-multiple-columns-in-join... i.e. `library(data.table); cols <- paste0('value', 1:2); setDT(df)[setDT(df.upd), (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols)), on=.(var1, var2, var3)]`

Answer (score 0):

It's a for-loop answer, but it still might be useful and fast, as the process is vectorized.

```
ind <- intersect(names(df), names(df.upd))
for (i in ind) {
  df[1:length(df.upd[,i]),i]  <- df.upd[,i]
}
```